# Shadow (cacheColorHint) for the list view

Tags: android, listview

I am getting a shadow like box for the  list view when I scroll the list in medium density mobiles. I have given the cacheColorHint as #00000000. I din't get what is that called? With what property I can remove that?

What I am getting is, when I place the cursor in front of the list view, a small file like icon appears and when I move the cursor it disappears. I don't know what is it called

Thanks in advance

Comment: For cacheColorHint you can read the blog written by Romain Guy : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Answer (score 1):

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

use this in your list view to disable fading edge effect.

Comment: Actually, Google search for fading edges in listviews directs people here. So its rather good to edit this question in a useful way. This answer will work if you are looking for how to remove shadows from listview top and bottom.